# How to delete all numbers from a string?

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

Below is an example of a test case:

```python
inpoot = "A.p.p.l.e (45) Orange (5.11) Kiwi"  # WE HAVE
outpoot = "A.p.p.l.e () Orange () Kiwi" # WE WANT
```

The only reason I spelled `inpoot` incorrectly is  because `input` is a reserved language keyword.

One might think that the following would work:

```python
import string
def kill_numbers(text: str) -> str:
    text = str(text)
    return "".join(filter(lambda ch: ch not in string.digits, text))
```

However, the decimal point (`.`) in a decimal numbers will be preserved.

```python
inpoot = "A.p.p.l.e (45) Orange T5.11T Kiwi 99 Apricot"

outpoot = kill_numbers(inpoot)
print(repr(outpoot))

# prints 'A.p.p.l.e  () Orange T.T Kiwi'
# We want `TT` not `T.T`
# the output contains a stray decimal point. 

outpoot = kill_numbers("Strawberry 3.145 Plum")
print(repr(outpoot))

# fails to delete the `.` in `3.145`
```

| INPUT | BAD OUTPUT | DESIRED OUTPUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `"3.14"` | `"."` | `""` (empty string) |

So, how can we delete all numbers, including decimal numbers?

A substitution using regular expressions is theoretically possible.

```python
import re
test_case =  "(.4) A.p.p.l.e (44) Orange .... (4.44) Kiwi . . . . ."
result = re.sub("[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+", "", test_case)
print(result) # () A.p.p.l.e () Orange .... () Kiwi . . . . .
```

The regular expression shown above works for that one test case, but not all test cases.

The table below shows how various regular expressions perform on various test inputs.

**KEY FOR TABLE**

- `-` means that the regex does *NOT* match the string
- `+` means that the regex matches the entire string
- `meh` means that the regex matches a small part of string, but not the whole thing.

| REGEX | `' 1 '` | `'2'` | `'3'` | `'365'` | `'9.43'` | `'-5000'` | `'+10'` | `'3.10.4'` | `'0001'` | `'.5'` | `'.'` | `'591.'` | `''` | `'0x77F'` | `'3.456e11'` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*|\\.[0-9]+` | - | - | - | - | - | meh | meh | meh | - | - | + | - | + | meh | meh |
| `[+-]?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*|\\.[0-9]+` | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | meh | - | - | + | - | + | meh | meh |
| `[+-]?([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*|\\.[0-9]+)` | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | meh | - | - | + | - | + | meh | meh |
| `[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*` | meh | - | - | - | - | meh | meh | meh | - | - | - | - | - | meh | meh |
| `[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]+` | + | + | + | - | - | meh | meh | meh | - | + | + | meh | + | meh | meh |
| `[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*` | - | - | - | - | - | meh | meh | meh | - | meh | + | - | + | meh | meh |
| `[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+` | - | - | - | - | - | meh | meh | meh | - | - | + | meh | + | meh | meh |
| `\\d+` | - | - | - | - | meh | meh | meh | meh | - | meh | + | meh | + | meh | meh |
| `[0-9]` | - | - | - | meh | meh | meh | meh | meh | meh | meh | + | meh | + | meh | meh |
| `\\d` | - | - | - | meh | meh | meh | meh | meh | meh | meh | + | meh | + | meh | meh |
| `\\d*` | meh | - | - | - | meh | meh | meh | meh | - | meh | meh | meh | - | meh | meh |

The same table in ASCII form might be easier to read and understand:

```
                                ' 1  ' '2' '3' '365' '9.43' '-5000' '+10' '3.10.4' '0001' '.5'  '.' '591.' '' '0x77F' '3.456e11'
[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+             -   -   -     -      -     meh   meh      meh      -    -    +      -  +     meh        meh
[+-]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+        -   -   -     -      -       -     -      meh      -    -    +      -  +     meh        meh
[+-]?([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)      -   -   -     -      -       -     -      meh      -    -    +      -  +     meh        meh
[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*                    meh   -   -     -      -     meh   meh      meh      -    -    -      -  -     meh        meh
[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+                      +   +   +     -      -     meh   meh      meh      -    +    +    meh  +     meh        meh
[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*                      -   -   -     -      -     meh   meh      meh      -  meh    +      -  +     meh        meh
[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+                      -   -   -     -      -     meh   meh      meh      -    -    +    meh  +     meh        meh
\d+                                  -   -   -     -    meh     meh   meh      meh      -  meh    +    meh  +     meh        meh
[0-9]                                -   -   -   meh    meh     meh   meh      meh    meh  meh    +    meh  +     meh        meh
\d                                   -   -   -   meh    meh     meh   meh      meh    meh  meh    +    meh  +     meh        meh
\d*                                meh   -   -     -    meh     meh   meh      meh      -  meh  meh    meh  -     meh        meh
```

In my humble opinion, regular expressions are a nightmare.

To digress, it took me a long time to realize that:

```
IMHO = In my humble opinion`. I don't speak acronym very well.
```

Back to business...

I cannot find a regex which satisfies the following requirements:

- the regex must ***not*** match the empty string (`""`)
- the regex must ***not*** match any sub-string of a version number, such as `"3.10.4"` At most one decimal point is allowed to appear in what we call a "number"
- the regex must ***not*** match free-floating decimal points (`"."`).

Desired behavior is as follows:

| PSEUDO-NUMBER | `IS_A_NUMBER()` | NOTES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `"1"` | Yes | int |
| `"2"` | Yes | int |
| `"365"` | Yes | int |
| `"365."` | No | `365.` is a float equivalent to `365.0` However, I do not want to delete the (`.`) at the end of the string `"The number of houses was 44."` |
| `"9.43"` | Yes | one decimal points |
| `"-5000"` | Yes |  |
| `"+10"` | Yes |  |
| `"0001"` | Yes |  |
| `".5"` | Yes | `.5` is equivalent to `0.5` |
| `"1"` | Yes |  |
| `"0x77F"` | Yes |  |
| `"3.456e11"` | Yes | pseudo-scientific-notation |
| `"3.10.4"` | **Not** a number | two decimals points |
| `"."` | **Not** a number |  |
| `""` | **Not** a number | do not match the empty string |

---

## EDIT:

The following are defined to be *seed numbers* ...

(`1`, `365`, `9.43`, `-5000`, `+10`, `0001`, `.5`, `.5`, `0x77F`, `3.456e11`)

A *valid number* is defined to be any *seed number* or a string formed by a *seed number* by doing one of the following:

1. Iteratively replacing any digit in a *seed number* with `99`
2. Replacing any digit in a *valid number* with a different digit.
3. Replacing `F` in `0xF` with `2F` or `F2` or `A`,`B`,`C` ,`D`, or `E`.

For example, you could replace the `5` in `-5000` with `9` to get `-9000`

Also, you could replace the `5` in `.5` with `99` to get `.99`

The above defines language **L**.

My question could be re-worded as follows:

What algorithm **A** will return ***s′*** from input string ***s*** such that:

- ***s*** is any finite-length string of ASCII characters.
- string ***s′*** is like string ***s*** except that all maximal substrings of ***s*** which are in language **L**, have been replaced by empty strings.

A substring **t** of string **s** is maximal and **t** is in language **L** if it is not possible to tack on one more character to the left or to the right of **t** to form **t′**, such that **t′** is a string in language **L** and **t′** is a substring of **s**.

In layman's terms, if you see "apple 12.345" you should go after "12.345" not "2.34".

Indices matter. Sometimes, it makes no sense to say that the letter `"a"` is a sub-string of `"abracadabra"`. Which letter "a" is it? It it the letter "a" third-from-the-left, or second-from-the left?

We define a ***string*** to a mathematical mapping **M** from a finite subset of the natural numbers to the ASCii character set such that the absolute difference between the maximum of the domain of mapping **M** and the minimum of the domain of mapping **M** is the sum of one and the cardinality of the domain of mapping **M**.

For any string **SML** and any string **LRG**, we say that **SML** is a sub-string of ***LRG*** if and only if **SML[k]** = **LRG[k]** for all **k** in the domain of *string* **SML**

## END OF EDIT

Comment: I think your problem is largely ill defined. 1- you have many unclear corner cases: `"My lucky number is 14."` Do you really want to consider the final `.` as part of the `14` making it a float? Is `"0x77"` to be interpreted as a single hex number or as the multiplication of decimal `0` with decimal `77` in which case you should retain the `x` multiplication symbol? 2- there are many other possible representation of numbers eg. romans `(ii)`, binary `0b0110` and so on...

Comment: @Julien the behavior for all of the corner cases is explained in a table appearing under the text "*Desired behavior is as follows*". As the table says, "0x77" to be interpreted as a single hex number. Our code does not know that humans use `x` for multiplication. We need not worry about roman numerals or binary `0b0110`. If it's not in the table of examples, then it should not be classified a number..... I regret that last sentence. I will add an edit to the bottom of the original question.

Comment: "`input` is a reserved language keyword" - [It isn't](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative lookarounds to avoid undesired corner cases. Use alternation patterns to include incompatible patterns such as hexadecimal numbers:

```
[+-]?(?:(?:\b(?<!\d\.)\d+(?:\.\d+)?|(?<!\d)\.\d+)(?!\.)(?:e\d+)?|\b0x[0-9A-F]+)\b
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/HXxct5/2

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> import re
>>> inpoot = "A.p.p.l.e (45) Orange (5.11) Kiwi"  # WE HAVE
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"\d+\.?\d*")
>>> re.sub(pattern, "", inpoot)
'A.p.p.l.e () Orange () Kiwi'
>>>
```

Comment: if `inpoot = "A (.9) B"` then your output is `"A (.) B"`, but the output is supposed to be `"A () B"`. Your code fails to delete the decimal point.